# Python Pandas compare 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Just wondering if anyone knows about comparing 2 df columns on python?

For example i have
Column 1
a1
a2
a3

Column 2
a123
a55
a21

Is there any way that I could show
a1 - Found in column 2
a2 - Not Found
a3 - Found in column 2

I have my 2 columns in dataframes (df and df1)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.isin`.

```py
df['1'].isin(df['2'])
```

Returns a Boolean series

Comment: I tried bull all items for df returned false

Comment: Right. Because none of the values in the DF column 1 are in column 2.